# No Activity Found to handle Intent in the class file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am pretty new to Android. I am learning about passing Intents within activities. Here is my code to pass Intent between 2 activties.

1. MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btOk);
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           EditText etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
           String Data = etName.getText().toString();

           Intent i = new Intent("com.adhish.passingintentdata.layout2");
           Bundle extras = new Bundle();
           extras.putString("Name", Data);
           i.putExtras(extras);
           startActivityForResult(i,1);
       }
   });
   }
   ```
2. layout2.java

   ```
   public class layout2 extends ActionBarActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout2);

   String myName = null;
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras != null)
   {
       myName = extras.getString("Name");
   }

   TextView tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData);
   tvData.setText(myName);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Manifest.xml

   ```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name=".layout2"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_layout2"
       android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.adhish.passingintentdata.MainActivity" />
   </activity>
   ```

When i run this code and click on the OK button to pass the data, my app crashes with a fatal error.

The error is:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.adhish.passingintentdata.layout2 (has extras) }
```

Please give me a detailed help about working with this issue, because I am new to Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, layout2.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this intent instead:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, layout2.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `com.adhish.passingintentdata.MainActivity` as Action string for creating Intent to launch `layout2` Activity :

```
    Intent i = new Intent("com.adhish.passingintentdata.layout2");
```

and in Manifast add intent-filter for  layout2 Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.adhish.passingintentdata.layout2" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: and how do i use com.adhish.passingintentdata.MainActivity as Action string for creating Intent to launch layout2 activity? where should i edit? @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @AdhishThite: no need to change just use `com.adhish.passingintentdata.MainActivity` instead of `com.adhish.passingintentdata.layout2`

Comment: @AdhishThite: and use same string which is used for action name in Manifest for creating intent

Comment: That's what I said a while ago. You call an intent from one activity to another.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi :  Both is different way to start Activity you suggest using target Activity name but OP is trying to start it using Action name

Comment: Yes different ways but same result.

Comment: @AdhishThite: see my answer now it will work in same way as you want

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Now I wonder which one of the answers is actually valid and widely used.

Comment: @AdhishThite:welcome. you are missing `<intent-filter>` in manifast is see later when you say it's not working

Comment: @AdhishThite: it's good to if you see [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) when use action's to start activity